# Refactoring options for a Java visitor

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, refactoring

I have a class that defines a transformation from an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) to an Intermediate Representation (IR) based on the visitor pattern. Both models are EMF models, so the visitor extends the abstract EMF Switch class of the AST model (I'm using Xtext to define the AST). The visitor has a state as a few private fields for the IR it is building (mapping of local variables, current procedure being translated, list of blocks to add instructions to, etc.).

The visitor implements methods for all constructs of the AST, so this goes from caseExpressionInteger to caseStatementIf, for a total of 21 public 'case' methods. I also have 22 private methods, and with the exception of a couple of methods that are just helpers, most of these are working with the state.

I'm now at a point where I find that the code is getting too long, and I would like to refactor it to make it easier to manage (e.g. by having smaller classes). My question is what options do I have?

Here is what I thought of:

- Have several classes extend one another, each class adding the implementation for some methods of the visitor
- Have several independent classes, and a 'main' class that delegates to these classes, passing them the state in a separate class
- Mix the two approaches (some delegate, some inherit)

Do you see another way? What would you consider best (easier to implement/maintain)? I believe this is a problem that many must have had, given that 'visitor' is quite common a pattern.

Comment: It is kind of hard to tell without more information. Could you expand a little bit? Assuming that the visitor is the class that is getting too long, can you show the set of methods that it implements? Which ones are public and which ones private? Maybe a little bit more of information about the models that you are mapping and the mapping itself?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the original question to add more information about the model and the visitor itself, this should help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it seems that the Visitor class is quite cohesive (which is good :)). The only thing that I may suggest is to move the translation logic to an IR [Builder](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html) and be the visitor the one that sends the commands to the builder (i.e. the Director role). In this case the builder would have the internal state, thus leveraging that burden from the visitor.

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how subclassing could fit in here to achieve your purposes, so I definitely go for delegation.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the best solution, this way I can choose how I distribute the complexity between the visitor and the builder.

Answer (score 1):

> a few private fields (the state that the visitor modifies/uses to do its work).

Sounds like another class to which some of the work would be delegated.

Generally speaking, you're likely better off looking for opportunities for delegation.

This isn't particularly specific to the presence of a Visitor pattern, and we really can't give a very complete answer without some more detail in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I did not know what level of detail I needed to provide, I have edited the original question.